# Select from two tables, one column

Tags: sql, database, select, interactive, multiple-tables

Please help me to write a Select :)

I need to return data from two tables: values from table X, but only these which also have value from table Y.
For example in table X values are:

| Column A | Column B | ---- |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Great | Orange | <- has attached photo which is located in table Y |
| Poor | Orange |  |
| Poor | Apple | <- has attached photo which is located in table Y |
| Awesome | Orange | <- has attached photo which is located in table Y |

I need to return values column A from table X, where value in column B is 'Orange' and only those which has attached photo in table Y.

Table X is in connection with table Y: **referencing constrains**

| Name | Table | Table owner | Unique | Columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Table_X | Table_Y | DBA | No | Table_X_id |

I tried this select, but it does not work properly, because it returns value 1 in every line where value is orange:

SELECT * FROM Table_X WHERE Table_X.Column_B='Orange' AND (EXISTS (select 1 from Table_Y att, Table_X orng where orng.Table_X_id=att.Table_X_id and att.Table_X_id is not null))

I hope it's clear.. help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
Select x.ColumnA from Table_X x
left join Table_Y y on y.Table_X_id = x.Table_X_id
where x.ColumnB = 'Orange' and and y.Att is not null
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a little change to the previously suggested query, if you need only the ones that appear on table Y, it should be an inner join:

```
SELECT Table_X.Column_A 
FROM Table_X 
INNER JOIN Table_Y
ON Table_X.Table_X_id=Table_Y.Table_X_id
WHERE Table_X.Column_B='Orange'
```